# What does capital W do in VIM?

Tags: vim

in VIM sometimes when saving, I accidentally hit capital W instead of its lowercase brother. I am prompted for my system password, so I assume it is running a sudo command of some sort, but do you know what?

Thank you!

Comment: in my vim it gives me "E492: Not an editor command: W" if i try to ":W".

Comment: Ahh..

thank you. I got the vimrc from a friend and it was:

w !sudo tee % > /dev/null

Comment: @tesmar That is sudo write, for when you open a vim instance using a non-elevated user but end up editing a file that you needed `sudo vim` for; tell your friend that [chrisbra/SudoEdit.vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/SudoEdit.vim) is a better version. That also allows SudoRead. You can still map :W to :SudoWrite for consistency.

Comment: Also, in case anyone else stumbles on this, the [fzf fuzzy finder](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) plugin defines `:Windows` which may pop up for `:W`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As others have said, `:W` isn't defined in vanilla vim (7.0 here), so it sounds like some plugin you've installed has added it.

`:command W` will tell you what it does.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you have a common mapping for `:W` in your `.vimrc`  to save the file as typing `:w` does. Often people press too long the shift key for the colon and make the typo but actually wanting to type `:w`. You've possibly got this mapping by copy and paste of snippets into your vimrc or by using a pre-configured vim setup such as [spf13-vim distribution](http://vim.spf13.com/).

.vimrc:

```
command! W  write
```

However, as pointed out by Sam Stokes checking the meaning of commands via

```
:command W
```

and for keycombos:

```
:verbose map < C-j>
```

is a general approach to find out what a command or keycombo does.

Answer (score 5):

You can test this line

```
{Cursor}It's the test
```

- `{Cursor}`: Cursor position
  in normal mode
- `w`: will move word which separated by " ,./?"

  - You will end up at `'s …`
- `W`: will move word which separated by " " only

  - You will end up at `the …`

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. The normal mapping of "W" advances by a WORD, where WORD is defined by a sequence of non-blank characters.

Comment: @bentsai: OP is not in control-mode but in ex-mode, as in "instead of :w he uses :W"

Comment: @akira that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

`:W` doesn't do anything in my copy of VIM (6.4), for what that's worth. What does `:help :W` tell you? (For me, it just takes me to the help for `:w`, which wouldn't be, um, **help**-ful for you. :-) )